# How to access value of an annotation contained in a UIMA RUTA rule

Tags: uima, ruta

I'm not sure if I'm doing this wrong, but I have this case. I have a list of words "stuff.txt" (for example), contains  `knife, fork, spoon`

Then a script like this

`DECLARE Stuff(INT count);
Document{-> MARKFAST(Stuff, StuffList, true)};
NUM Stuff -> Update stuff count`

And then, in my text most of the time I'll have something like `3 knifes, 2 spoons` for example.

Is there a way to get the number value and update the annotation ? Or use gather to update the annotation itself ? Assign the NUM annotation.ct to my Stuff.count value or something of that sort without creating another type like `DECLARE NewStuff(Stuff stuff, INT count)` and use gather.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
DECLARE Stuff(INT count);
Document{-> MARKFAST(Stuff, {"knifes", "spoons"}, true)};
INT amount;
NUM{PARSE(amount)} s:@Stuff{-> s.count = amount};
```

The PARSE condition is used to convert the covered text to an integer.

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Comment: what does the "@" symbol do ? Thanks for the snippet, it worked

Comment: It's  a marker identifying the anchor of the rule. The rule will start matching with the second rule element, and does not need to check every NUM. Please mind that the selection of the starting rule lement can change the resulting annotations.